# Google App Engine order by a property

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am writing a query which involves inequality filter.

```
query = my_model.all().filter('my_date <', given_date)
```

I want to sort the results by some other property. The problem is according to documentation i have to order the results by the inequality property first.

Does anyone know how can i sort my results by some other property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that documentation is correct.

You could sort the result set in memory.

You would have to provide more information about the other attributes. It might be possible to provide a single aggregate property that suits sort and the filter.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the "after-fetch-sort". It may result in an incorrect list (since some entities might not been fetched).

```
query = my_model.all().filter('my_date <', given_date).fetch()
query.sort(key=lambda x: x.my_sort_property)
```

Can't remember but [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) might let you order + filter, but don't think so. Check it out, it's still much better then the old datastore API.